# Can I use a Logitech M505 wireless mouse with Fedora?

Tags: fedora, mouse

It's a nice mouse, but Fedora 15 doesn't recognize it.  In /proc/bus/input/devices, I see a "PS/2 Generic Mouse".  I've tried booting into Fedora with the USB device still plugged in, and it hangs.

I found instructions that might work for Ubuntu, but they involve editing a file I just don't have in Fedora (/etc/X11/xorg.conf).

Comment: [You might not *need* `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but you *may have one*.](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf)

Comment: @sr_:  I looked for any sort of xorg.conf. There's stuff in /etc/X11, but not xorg.conf, and doing a `find . -name \*org.conf` from the root directory didn't get anything.

Comment: @DavidThornley Follow the link that sr_ gave you: it explains how to create the file. X will run with sensible defaults if the file is absent, but “exotic” hardware may require the file to be present, with “exotic” settings.

Comment: You should look at the output of `dmesg` and `lsusb -v`

Comment: USB mice don't show up as PS/2 mice. Womething is very wrong there.

Comment: FWIW, my Fedora 16 system has shown no problems with any of its hardware.